# Resetting HP printer's catridges

Tags: windows-7, printing, cartridge

I have a HP Desk jet 2131 printer with HP 803 cartridges. Today i have refilled the black cartridges but after inserting the cartridge in the printer it recognize the cartridge but it  shows the ink level of the cartridge when it was not refilled in the estimated ink level window. Is there any way to make the printer to show the ink level of refilled cartridges.

Is there any utility available which monitors ink levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1:

- Remove both the black and the color ink HP cartridges from your printer.
- Press the 'On' button on your printer to turn it on, wait 20 seconds, then turn it off. Allow the printer to completely turn off. Repeat this step five times so that the HP cartridge identification information will be erased from the printer's memory. HP printers normally store the identification information of the last five ink cartridges that were used. This will make the printer 'remember' the last 5 cartridges as 'none'.
- Insert back the cartridges inside the printer. Print a test page to ensure the cartridge level system is reset.

Method 2: A full reset of the printer should also do:

- Remove the cartridges and unplug the printer.
- Hold the power button on for 30+ seconds. Then release.
- Plug in printer and reinstall cartridges one at a time.

Method 3:

- Remove the cartridge and on the 2nd contact column from the left, place adhesive tape over the top contact in that column.
- Place the cartridge back into the printer. A message may show up that there is an issue with your cartridge. Ignore it. Print an alignment page.
- Take the same cartridge out of the printer when the alignment page is done.
- Do not touch or remove the tape that was originally put on the cartridge. Now grab adhesive tape and put it over the 2nd column from the right, on the top contact.
- Place the cartridge into the printer again. Let it be detected.
- Take the cartridge out of the printer one more time, and remove all adhesive tape.
- Put the cartridge back again into the printer. Print again an alignment page and the ink level should show full.

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately none of the above methods worked.

Comment: Method 1 works for a refill cartridge HP Deskjet 990cxi but close the cover after removing the cartridges before starting the on - off procedure. dcw

Comment: Unfortunately, on an HP ENVY 5540 and cartridge HP 62, none of the 3 methods worked for me.